# jQuery logic involving an event and if/else statement and a form

Tags: jquery, html, logic

This is probably obvious to an experienced developer, but I'm trying to teach myself jQuery and I came across this. Say I have a button with id 'btn' and the Html is 'Msg 1'
I want to change the Html to 'Msg 2' when the button is clicked.
This is the way I tried to do it, and it works. But this way won't work if the button is part of a form. Is there a way to do it when the button is part of a form?

```
(function($) {
   var test = true;
   $('#btn').on('click',function() {
        if(test == true) {
            test = false;
            $(this).html('Msg 2');
        } else {
            test = true;
            $(this).html('Msg 1');
        }
   }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: If it's a part of a form should not matter

Comment: By "part of a form," do you mean it's <input type="button" /> or still <button></button>?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some JSFiddle code, which does what you asked for:

http://jsfiddle.net/RSVdw/1/

Changed the .html()'s to .val()'s and added an e.preventDefault() so that the form wouldn't refresh the entire page when pressed.

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form>
        Press me &gt;&gt; <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Msg 1"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>​
```

JS Code:

```
(function($) {
   var test = true;
   $('#btn').on('click',function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        if(test == true) {
            test = false;
            $(this).val('Msg 2');
        } else {
            test = true;
            $(this).val('Msg 1');
        }
   });
})(jQuery);​
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question properly but you can try this.

```
$('#btn').live('click', function(event) 
    {

         $(this).val('Msg 2');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above are correct, but there is no need to use 'on' or the deprecated 'live' unless the button is dynamically created.

```
$('#btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //.. prevent the button from submitting the form
    test = !test;
    $(this).text(test ? 'msg 1' : 'msg 2'); //.. no need to use .html if you're just switching text
});
```

**note:** this solution is assuming you are using `<button>`, if you are using `<input type='submit|button'>`, you will need to use `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).text()`